# Restrict login email with Google (HWIOAuthBundle) to specific Domain in Symfony

Tags: symfony, hwioauthbundle

How can I restrict logging into Google to an specific domain from **HWIOAuthBundle** in symfony2 (`hd` parameter). ¿Where can I write it?

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#authenticationuriparameters)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may write it inside the options parameter for the resource owners. E.g.:

```
# config.yml
resource_owners:
    google:
        type:                google
        client_id:           "%google_client_id%"
        client_secret:       "%google_client_secret%"
        scope:               "email profile"
        options:
            hd:              "yourdomain.com"
            access_type:     offline
```

As referenced by this issue:
https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/issues/216

Comment: Do you know if it is posible to improve the HD parameter to accept array?